# Suricata: [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Coudn't set fanout mode, error Invalid argument

Tags: networking, security

I set up suricata on my server (via docker container). It works really great on one of my interfaces.
But If I create another container for another interface the container stops with exit code 0 and the following message:

```
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Couldn't init AF_PACKET socket, fatal error
<Notice> - Signal Received.  Stopping engine.
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Coudn't set fanout mode, error Invalid argument
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Coudn't set fanout mode, error Invalid argument
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Coudn't set fanout mode, error Invalid argument
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Couldn't init AF_PACKET socket, fatal error
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Couldn't init AF_PACKET socket, fatal error
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Couldn't init AF_PACKET socket, fatal error
<Notice> - Stats for 'ens256':  pkts: 0, drop: 0 (-nan%), invalid chksum: 0
```

I am not very familiar with packet aquisition or af_packet. Could someone give me a hint what it could be?

The network interface ens256 is running/up.

Answer (score 0):

As work around, explicitly set 'threads' to 1 in the af-packet section of your yaml for the interface you are using.